# How to interact with gui application using windows service

Tags: java, windows, service

I have an application in java in which I have start and stop buttons in swing. I want to make a windows service which automatically clicks on start button. Is it possible and if it's possible how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You must find a way to identify the main window of your swing application from the Windows service (common usage is the title bar)

Then, you search in subwindows how to identify the `Start` button (generally the id, but you could use text)

All that must be done only once, using the Windows SDK tools and/or you knowing from the GUI application

Now the service :

- searches the top-level windows for the right one
- searches the relevant button
- gets it position
- uses `SendInput` API function to simulate a `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` and `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` event over the button

The last part could be done in Java (with `Robot`), but the others will need to use Windows API